# Manifest won't allow correct name format, says Activity does not exist when changed

Tags: android, manifest

The problem is with the `ServerStatus.ServerStatusActivity`. The application will not install because of the incorrect Activity name, but if I change it then it says package does not exist. I have a background in C++ and I have learned Android/Java self-taught over last week. I know my format is rough, and I apologize.

Could it be that incorrectly added a new Activity?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="d3.link"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

        <uses-sdk android:maxSdkVersion="15"
              android:targetSdkVersion="10"
              android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/d3l"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".D3LinkActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET" android:name="ServerStatusActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: what is your actual package name?

Comment: I have 2 packages, d3.link and ServerStatus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The activity's name must be in the same way you declared the D3LinkActivity. You provided the package name within the manifest's root. When you declare an activity, you can either provide the full name (full package name + '.' + class name) or provide a relative path to your class ('.' + part of the package name + class name).

For example:

You have a class at d3.link.ui.SampleActivity. After providing "d3.link" in the manifest, you can either declare your activity with "d3.link.ui.SampleActivity" or ".ui.SampleActivity".

The way you're providing this, it's like you have a package called "ServerStatus" and a class called "ServerStatusActivity" or a "ServerStatus" in the root package with a nested class called "ServerStatusActivity".

Comment: I have 2 packages, one package called "ServerStatus" and a class called "ServerStatusActivity" The other package D3Link and the class D3LinkActivity

Comment: I edited my original code with more of what I actually should be trying to do. Now I'm getting a root element must be well formed. How would I make a second manifest as my searches lead me to believe I need it in a separate file?

Comment: This is a strange package's name, but I think it should work. I saw your edit and it's wrong. You can't specify two 'manifest' tags in the same xml. Look this link: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/android/fundamentals. It show that it's possible to declare an activity with its full path name (com.google.ads.AdActivity).

Comment: You can't specify two files in an application nor specify two manifest in the same file. Look at the sample in my previous comment and try changing this package name. This name looks much strange. I don't know if android does matter about it, but a normal package name is downcase and can have some names separated by dots.

Comment: I changed the manifest to the one that ended up working now. What I did to fix it is removed the second package and rolled the SeverStatusActivity.java into the d3.link package and reset my build path. This corrected my problems and the program is up and running again.

Answer (score 0):

You must provide in your manifest tag, http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#package
In Android, the system search one component in application, by the Package_Name +
the component's name, like com.google + .activity1, so the activity path is com.google.activity1. 
Hope this help you.

Comment: Yes that did help me for the future naming and such, thank you! I just need to figure out how to recover from this flub.